# How to use this "combined" data type: (int, int)[]

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing kata over at codewars.com and one of them involves an array of intervals:

```
(int, int)[] intervals
```

I assume that's equivalent to an array of KeyValuePair, but how does one access either integer?

Comment: Did you type `intervals[0].` and see what code completion spits out?

Comment: @nvoigt I was working on codewars, and there's no code completion. Didn't think about firing up the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [`Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) data type. In your sample you can access a tuple item using `Item1` and `Item2` properties (because it's an [unnamed tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples)), like that:

```cs
(int, int)[] intervals = new (int, int)[3];
var interval = intervals[0];
var item1 = interval.Item1;
var item2 = interval.Item2;
```

It was available before C# 7.

In C# 7 and later versions you can also declare an array of [named tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) `(int x, int y)[] intervals` and access an items using named properties, `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 4):

That is an array of an [unnamed tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#named-and-unnamed-tuples). By default, you would use "Item1", "Item2" to access the properties.

```cs
foreach(var interval in intervals) {
  Console.WriteLine(interval.Item1);
  Console.WriteLine(interval.Item2);
}
```